# cs-cart create new iframe and send payment in it

Tags: jquery, payment-gateway, cs-cart

I need to create new iframe in last payment page and change form target to this iframe.

When click buy now button in payments 4th page (triggered by ajax you know), form must be submit in that iframe.

If i refresh page its working but when i go to step1->2->3-> and 4 (4 loaded by ajax) this is not working. Or if i refresh page and go to page3 and again page4 it is not working. Or if i change payment method and turn back again it is not working.

**v4.3x+**

I tried to use:

```
(function(_, $) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("form[name='payments_form_{$tab_id}']").attr("target","2frame");
        $("form[name='payments_form_{$tab_id}'] .ty-checkout-buttons").parent().prepend('<div id="3dlayer" class="3dlayer" style="height:600px; border:1px solid gray; background-color:white; border-radius:2px; overflow:auto; "><iframe width="100%" height="100%" name="2frame" id="2frame" src=""></iframe></div>'); //addingiframe
        $(".3dlayer").hide();
        $("form[name='payments_form_{$tab_id}']").on("submit",function(e) { //when submit i need to post that page to that new frame

        if ($('#id_accept_terms{$tab_id}:checked').length == 1) { //there is only accept terms checkbox and submit(pay now) form button
            $(".3dlayer").show();
            $("form[name='payments_form_{$tab_id}']").attr("target","2frame"); //again i am trying to set

           if (!$("form[name='payments_form_{$tab_id}']").hasClass("protex")) { 
               $("form[name='payments_form_{$tab_id}']").attr("target","2frame"); //and agin
               $(".protex").submit();  //now form must be open in iframe
           }
            $("form[name='payments_form_{$tab_id}']").addClass("protex"); //i am using this for protecting on.submit recursion.
            $(document).scrollTop( 350 );
            return true;
        } 

        if($(".3dlayer").attr("display") == "none") return false;
    });

    $("#2frame").on("load", function(){
        $(".ty-ajax-overlay,.ty-ajax-loading-box").fadeOut(); //if iframe works,    here is working.
        $(document).scrollTop( 100 );
        return false;
    });

});

}(Tygh, Tygh.$));
```

- i used class cm-ajax-force, and tried to not use.
- i tried to not use `function( tygh.`
- opposite i tried to not use document.ready function.
- i tried to use this code in hooks 4th   page.pre|post
- i tried to add that div at the top of my `payment.tpl without
  append()`
- I also tried other bulls** ways.

Waiting suggestions.

Comment: reformatted code to make it readable, people are trying to put effort into helping you so try helping them as much as you possibly can - scanning code is a lot easier if it's organised and easy to read, people will also more likely want to put effort into helping you if you've put effort in.

Comment: sorry about this. you are true, i am not good at using stack but i am trying to learn. thanks for your edit.